# Autorun Python Script for 50 files

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, export

Is there any ways to auto run my python scripts? because i need to run the same scripts for 50 files.

In my script i also have this export command:

```
datatoexcel = pandas.ExcelWriter('File1.xlsx') 
  

data2.to_excel(datatoexcel) 
  
 
datatoexcel.save() 
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

For export files, I need to have 50 excel files( File 1-File 50). Is there a ways to automate all this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to export the same dataset which is data2 then the following code should work

```
for i in range(1,51):
    filename = f"File{i}.xlsx"
    data2.to_excel(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Save this file as Autorun.py :

```
import winreg as reg  
import os              
  
def AddToRegistry(address):
    key = HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
    key_value = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
    open = reg.OpenKey(key,key_value,0,reg.KEY_ALL_ACCESS)
    reg.SetValueEx(open,"any_name",0,reg.REG_SZ,address)
    reg.CloseKey(open)
  
if __name__=="__main__": 
    path="C:/.../file.py"
    AddToRegistry(path)
    print("File is successfully saved for autorun")
```

This program will save your file for autorun at startup ( only for windows )